# Why different cpu pairs take different time to execute the same code

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've created program that takes arguments from argv and creates for each one a thread with thread affinity set to int value of the argument. 
For example
`./main 3 4`
will create two threads, the first one will run on the third cpu and second thread will utilize the fourth cpu.

One thread takes one second to complete (doing math operations on array int[10000])
When I run `time ./main 1 2` I saw expected 1 second real time
But when I run `time ./main 1 3` I saw 2 seconds instead of 1
I thought this has something to do with numa nodes, but
`time ./main 1 4` resulted in 1 second real time

After more tests I saw that only 1 3 and 2 4 pairs take twice as much time than expected. Also the user time is also twice as big.

```sh
$ time ./main 1 2
real    0m1.058s
user    0m2.100s

$ time ./main 1 3
real    0m2.019s
user    0m4.016s

$ time ./main 1 4
real    0m1.090s
user    0m2.152s

$ time ./main 2 4
real    0m2.014s
user    0m4.016s

$ time ./main 2 3
real    0m1.094s
user    0m2.156s

$ time ./main 3 4
real    0m1.170s
user    0m2.316s
```

The code I was testing. I skipped `set_affinity` function

```cpp
void math_ops() {
  size_t len = 14800; // with this number it takes around 1s to compute on my hardware
  int* abc = new int[len+1];
  memset(abc, 7, len);
  for(int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j < len; j++) {
      abc[i] *= abc[j];
      abc[j+1] -= abc[i-1];
      abc[j-1] -= abc[i+1];
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::vector<std::thread> vec(argc);
  int thread_num = argc - 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < thread_num; i++) {
    std::thread t(math_ops);
    // sets thread affinity equal to the second parameter
    set_affinity(t, atoi(argv[i+1]) - 1);
    vec[i] = std::move(t);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < thread_num; i++) {
    vec[i].join();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know why cpu pairs 1,3 and 2,4 take twice as much time to execute?

Comment: Unrelated, but whenever you are thinking `new T[size]`, you should use a `vector<T>` instead. Also, the following `memset()` call looks fishy.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, thanks, noted

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt but doing that made code run twice as slow
I've replaced `int*` and `memset` with `std::vector<int> abc(len, 7);`
I guess I should use `int abc[14800]` instead;

Comment: Well, one operates on `len` bytes, the other on `len` integers. Also, only one releases the memory again.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Right! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be due to [hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).
The four cores you see aren't really 4 cores, they're probably just two cores, with twice as many execution units. That means that two threads that run on virtual cores that belong to the same physical core have to share some of that core's resources.

When you're running on two different physical cores, there's no sharing of resources and the code executes faster.

You can find out which cores are siblings by reading `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/topology/thread_siblings_list` (replace `cpu0` with any other core#)

Comment: Thanks!
I checked and you are right. 
First and third cpus are on the same core